# Extract numbers from a 1 line string using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a one line string that looks like this:

```
{"took":125,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":10,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}{"took":365,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":10,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}{"took":15,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":10,"successful":10,"skipped":0,"failed":0}}
```

I would like to extract all the numbers after the "took" part, so in my case the output would look like this:

```
125
365
15
```

What I've tried so far is using `took":(\d{1,6}),"(.*)` as a regex. But since its a one line string, it only extracts the first occurence and ignores the others.

Comment: You can use this pattern to get the numbers `"took":\K\d+`

Comment: Or, find `took":(\d+)|(?s)(?:(?!took":\d).)*` and replace with `(?{1}$1\n)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is an interesting find / replace with the conditional.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it works great! If you don't mind explaining the logic behind in an answer, I would gladly accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

*Find What*:      `took":(\d+)|(?s)(?:(?!took":\d).)*`
*Replace With*: `(?{1}$1\n)`

*Details*:

- `took":` - literal text
- `(\d+)` - one or more digits captured into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `(?s)` - set the DOTALL mode on (`.` matches line break chars now)
- `(?:(?!took":\d).)*` - any single char, zero or more times, as many as possible, that does not start a `took":`  + digit char sequence.

The `(?{1}$1\n)` conditional replacement pattern replaces this way:

- `(?{1}` - if Group 1 is matched

  - `$1\n` - replace the match with Group 1 and a newline
- `)` - else, replace with an empty string.